# Почему письмо с сервера (через php код) то приходит ко мне на почту, то нет?

Tags: javascript, php, сервер, email, backend

Я хочу отправлять письма с каким-то текстом с сервера (хостинг и домен на [reg.ru](https://reg.ru)) себе на почту. Код ниже. Самое странное - это тот факт, что письмо то приходит на почту, то нет. Никак не пойму, от чего это может зависеть. Если у Вас есть какие-то идеи, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
$message = 'Random Text';
$to = 'm.y.mail.for.site@mail.ru';
$spectext = '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><title>Заказ</title></head><body>';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

$mailSent = mail($to, 'Заказ в магазине MementoMori', $spectext.$message.'</body></html>', $headers);

if ($mailSent) {echo 1;} else {echo 0;}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в спам. И изменяйте письма.

Comment: В спаме тоже нет, проверял

Comment: Это mail.ru. он может фильтровать письма

Comment: Попробуйте другой сервер

Comment: Я не думаю, что причина в этом, так как на стадии тестирования своего скрипта мне по ошибке приходило по 3-5 писем за одно мгновение

Comment: Письмо должно проходить проверку подлинности. Оно должно прийти с того IP-адреса, для которого прописано соответствующее разрешение в SPF-записи домена отправителя, а также оно должно быть подписано DKIM-ключом того домена, с которого отправляется. Письмо, не имеющее доказательств своей подлинности, может быть расценено как спам